# Implicit parameter definition in nonlinear programming

Tags: derivatives, optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I'm solving the following convex optimization problem:
$(p^\ast_{L_i},p^\ast_{H_i}, r^\ast)=\text{argmax}_{p_{L_i},p_{H_i}, r} \left\{ r\sum_i \left[ p_{L_i} N^B_{L_i}  + p_{H_i} N^B_{H_i}  \right ] \right\}$

$\text{subject to} \,\,\, N^S_i = N^{B}_{H_i} + (1+x_i)N^{B}_{L_i} \\ 
\qquad \qquad \quad  \,\,     x_i = \frac{p_{H_i}-p_{L_i}}{d} \\ 
\qquad \qquad \, \, \, \, \,   N^B_{L_i} \geq 0 \\
\qquad \qquad \quad \, \, \, \, \,     0 \leq x_i, r \leq 1$

Where $N^B_{L_i}$, $N^B_{H_i}$, $N^S_i$ are defined as follows:

$N^S_i = 1- F^S\left(\frac{N^B_{H_i}(p_{H_i}-r)+ N^B_{L_i}(p_{L_i}-r)}{N^B_{H_i}+(1-x_i)N^B_{L_i}+2 x_i N^B_{L_i}}\right)$

$N^B_{L_i} = F^B\left(\frac{p_{H_i} -p_{L_i}}{x_i}\right) - F^B\left(\frac{s-p_{L_i}}{1+x_i}\right) $

$N^B_{H_i} = 1- F^B\left(\frac{p_{H_i} -p_{L_i}}{x_i}\right)$

So $d$,$s$, and our CDFs $F^B$ and $F^S$ are givens. Everything else is unknown. But I'm not sure how to handle the $x_i$ terms. My understanding of what I am trying to model is that $x_i$ should be pinned down (in expectation) by the prices, ex-post seeing prices. So I can't define $x_i$ unless it's a parameter of the model or an unknown variable (in Python, to solve numerically). Anyone have any experience with the constraint implicitly defining the objective function? This does seem similar to the dual problem in convex optimization, so I think it has to be doable!

Comment: Can you formulate constraint(s) in terms of the optimization variables (does that includes prices?) to force the expected value of the $x_i$ to have the required values? That would then perhaps amount to constraining some function of prices which are optimization variables?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've been thinking about the problem more, and I don't think I can reformulate the constraints in the manner that you are asking. Although if you have an idea I'd love to hear it. I did however think that perhaps I could assume that the $x_i$ follow some distribution, initially, so numerically I can feed an initial set of $x^{0}_{i}$ and then optimize over prices. Then optimize with the initial set, to obtain initial prices. Then initial prices determine my first set of $x_i$. Then, my outputted optimizers will become better and better over time. Does this make sense?

Comment: There are some contract-theoretic implications to not having the 2nd set of constraints bind. These are some properties of the behavior I am trying to capture with the model (see monopolistic screening).

Comment: Your description is not clear enough. Are the p's in the formula for $x_ii$ the prices you refer to, and are they the same p's which are the decision (optimization) variables? If there is a dynamic (time) aspect, you are not making it clear. If you need some equilibrium condition to hold as a constraint to your optimization problem, you may have an MPEC - they arise when equilibrium prices are needed, or as the KKT conditions to inner optimization problem of a bi-level optimization problem. Anyhow you needed to clarify how $x_ii$ and prices are determined, and do so in a mathematical way.

Comment: There is no dynamic time aspect. I care about finding the optimal prices (the  p's) and an optimal rate (r). However, our functions for determining low $NL_i$ and high demand  $NH_i$ (which determine profit) depend on this parameter $x_i$. However, my only way of knowing what the $x_i$ are is through that 2nd constraint. I simply care about finding the profit maximizing prices (and rate).

Comment: In terms of how a firm would have to profit maximize - they would set some initial prices, assuming some values of $x_i$, and then they would be able to profit maximize (ignoring the 2nd set of constraints). Ex post profit maximizing, they could use the 2nd set of constraints to see what the true $x_i$ would look like? This part I'm less sure about.

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do with the $x_i$.  Can you make them optimization variables and specify constraints they must satisfy in terms of other optimization variables and input parameters? Then the optimization solver will determine their values at the optimal solution.If you need to compute an expectation, then you will have to decide on a probability distribution to use in calculating it.